# What direction is the fold procedure in MIT Scheme?

Tags: scheme, reduce, fold, mit-scheme

If I want to reverse a list in MIT Scheme, I can do it with `(fold cons '() list)` such that if list is `(define lis '(1 2 3 4))`, then `(fold cons '() lis)` gives `(4 3 2 1)`. There are two kinds of folds, left and right folds, but if I use `(fold-right cons '() lis)`, I get `(1 2 3 4)` so the plain fold can't be that one. Also if I use `(fold-left cons '() lis)` I get `((((() . 1) . 2) . 3) . 4)` so that also cannot be the fold in the original example. what kind of fold is needed to reverse a list?

I ask because I want to be able to make a generic fold such that:

```
(define ls '((1 2 3) (4 5 6)))
(gen-fold cons '() ls)
=> ((6 5 4) (3 2 1))
(define l2 '(((1 2) (2 3)) ((3 4) (4 5))))
(gen-fold cons '() ls)
=> (((5 4) (4 3)) ((3 2) (2 1)))
```

Edit: Inorder to better present the questions, these diagrams depict the rotation of the list that I believe to be happening when  `'(fold cons '() '(1 2 3))` is called assuming that `fold` is a modified `fold-left` as per alexis king:

```
(define lis (list '(1 2 3))

     cons
    /   \
   1    cons
        /  \
       2   cons
           /  \
          3   '()

(cons lis '())

         cons
        /  \
      cons '()
     /  \
    1   cons
       /   \
      2    cons
           /  \
          3   '()

(fold-left (cons lis '()))

        cons
       /    \
    cons     cons
   /  \      /  \
  2   cons  1   '()
      /  \
     3   '()


        cons
       /    \
    cons     cons
   /  \       /  \
  3   '()    2    cons
                  /   \
                1     '()

   cons
  /  \
 3   cons
     /  \
    2   cons
        /  \
       1   '()
```

Comment: The base MIT Scheme environment does not include a `fold` function, only `fold-left` and `fold-right`. The only semi-builtin `fold` I can think of would be from SRFI-1. Are you including anything that would introduce a definition for `fold`?

Comment: Well it would appear that it is a builtin  because with a fresh install of mit-scheme I can go in and type `(fold cons '() '(1 2 3))` and get `=> (3 2 1)` without defining fold

Comment: *"what kind of fold is needed to reverse a list?"* left fold with the { `cons` with flipped order of arguments }.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MIT Scheme does not include a `fold` function in its base library, only [`fold-left` and `fold-right`](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/testing/mit-scheme-ref/Folding-of-Lists.html). However, there does exist a [`fold`](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#fold) function as declared by SRFI-1, which is supported by MIT Scheme and exhibits the behavior you describe.

The `fold` function is a left fold—that is, it accumulates the list by left-to-right iteration—but it differs from MIT Scheme's `fold-left` function in that the argument order of the accumulator procedure is flipped. That is, `fold` applies the supplied procedure with the accumulator argument *last*, while `fold-left` applies the procedure with the accumulator argument *first*.

To illustrate that point, this is how one could define `fold` in terms of `fold-left`:

```
(define (fold proc init lst)
  (fold-left (lambda (x acc) (proc acc x)) init lst))
```

In my experience, the `fold` argument order tends to be more common among Lisp implementations, while the `fold-left` argument order tends to be more common among other functional languages. The reason for the `acc` argument to be supplied *last* is for precisely the reason you discovered: it makes it easier to use `fold` with `cons`-like procedures that accept the accumulated value as their second argument.

---

As an aside, you appear to have mixed up `fold-left` and `fold-right` in your original question: it is `fold-right` that returns the list unchanged and `fold-left` that returns the inverted set of pairs. If you understand how `fold-left` and `fold-right` are defined, this makes sense.

In a certain sort of way, both `fold-left` and `fold-right` fold over lists starting from the *left*, since Scheme lists are singly-linked and cannot be read from the right. The difference is that left folding is iterative while right folding is recursive.

A left fold applies a procedure to each element one by one, then threads the result into the next application. This ends up reversing the order of the elements when viewed as nested applications:

```
(proc eN ... (proc e1 (proc e0 init)) ...)
```

In contrast, a right fold applies the procedure recursively, keeping the order consistent in nested applications:

```
(proc e0 (proc e1 ... (proc eN init) ...))
```

When used with `cons`, the left fold reverses, but the right fold is just the identity.

(This is potentially more interesting in lazy languages like Haskell because right folding does not depend on the entire list despite supposedly starting "from the right", so it can operate on infinite streams... however, this is much less relevant in Scheme.)